# I'm not able to access my remote machine without password

Tags: unix, freebsd

I am working on Free BSD and I need to connect to my remote machine without password.

I tried the following but I can't log into the remote machine without password.

Logs:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@mydomain.net:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I just tried to log into that machine, and It is still asking for the password.

I have been stuck on this issue the past month.

Comment: Please add more information about your situation. Is there a password on the remote machine for the user you are trying to log in as? What is the remote OS?

Comment: Hi,My Remote os is BSD

Comment: Before  two month back it's working fine.Logs:
Fri Jul 18  [sureshjd@hcl-odc-sunray2:~]ssh -t hcl-odc-shell2 "bash"
Password:
Fri Jul 18  [sureshjd@hcl-odc-shell2:~]ls -l ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw-r--r--  1 sureshjd  ft  234 Jul 17 19:15 /homes/sureshjd/.ssh/authorized_keys
Fri Jul 18  [sureshjd@hcl-odc-shell2:~]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are the permissions for authorized_keys and its parent?  You might try:

```
chmod go-w ~
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```